# STP Protocol and Sonnos CONNECT issue

Tags: home-networking, switch

My father-in-law has a huge fluctuation in his wireless connection throughout the day. On average, the speed is about 72 Mbps / 30 Mbps and drops to 0.5 Mbps / 0 Mbps for several minutes.

He hired professionals but the issue is nowhere to be resolved.

I emailed the guy and he says that the issue might be something as follows:

We have Root Layer 2 switch which connects 6 other Layer 2 switches in the household. Each of these 6 switches has AP connected to it. The Sonos system is connected to a dummy switch and Sonos speakers are allocated throughout the household.

What he claims to be the issue is that the Sonos devices "advertises false network routes" which possibly creates loops?

Am I incorrect to assume that this cannot happen because STP Protocol is just between the switches and the Sonos devices don't have influence over the topology of the network?

Thank you!

EDIT: I would like to add that during the time when the wireless speed drops, I tried the speed through my LAN cable and it was at 300 Mbps (down) / 30 Mbps (up).

Also, it happened once that there wasn't speed at all, even running through LAN.

Below is a screenshot of channels used for our devices at the house. The devices are set for auto-channel.

[image: I added screenshot of channels used for our devices at the house]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Network routes are layer-3, but STP is layer-2. The two have nothing to do with each other. STP prevents layer-2 loops, where broadcasts feed and grow until your network crashes (nearly instantly). Routing loops also exist, but the layer-3 packet TTL will limit and halt a packet loop. It really sounds like there is intermittent wireless interference.

Comment: I would start by capturing some very basic information in a log file over time.  For example, the following Powershell - https://pastebin.com/qtryzNHr.  Add the contents of that to a file called `WifiRecord.ps1`, then in a command prompt run: `powershell ./WifiRecord.ps1 -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`.  If you leave that running for a few hours or after you know the problem has occurred.  What does the data look like in `WifiLog.txt` (same dir as script), you can open it up in Excel as it's a CSV.  Maybe start there and then look to collect other data.

Comment: Am I understanding this question correctly to be a wireless problem? As Ron commented these are different layers in action. If this "professional" didn't come with a wifi spectrum analyzer, he was guessing at what the issue might be. (And a poor uneducated guess at that)  I would lean on wireless interference with this, as the throughout changes throughout the day. Maybe update us to the channels these 6 AP's are on, as it would be difficult to honeycomb a 2.4ghz network in a home with out interference from your own adjacent AP's.

Comment: Thank you very much fellaz. I'll update the post as soon as I'll get the information.